# jPlayer complains about valid swfPath

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, jplayer

**Major update at end of post**

I'm initializing jPlayer with the following code.  It's working great on all modern browsers and on mobile devices.

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        supplied: "mp3",
        swfPath: "/js/jQuery.jPlayer.2.4.0",
        solution: "html,flash",
        errorAlerts: true,
        ended: function () {
            console.log('ended event fired');
            $.getScript('/js/random_show.js.php');
        }
    });
```

However testing in IE 8 and IE 7 I get the following error from the fallback SWF player:

[image: error message]

If I open mysite.com/js/jQuery.jPlayer.2.4.0  the SWF loads without issue.  I have tried letting the page sit for a while to see if that helped.  It does not.

Per suggestion tried with working URL but have same error now with complete path listed.  Path taken from browser after loading swf so most definitely correct. I had pasted code here but SO objected to body of post containing the URL...  Here is new error message.

[image: new error]

Another update: Tried linking directly to copy of SWF hosted by jPlayer per Josh D suggestion below.  Same error.  Upgraded to 2.5.0 from 2.4.0. Same error.

[image]

How can I get the fallback working?

**Major update 12/12/2013**

I have set up a sandbox copy of the site here:  http://www.itsneworleans.dreamhosters.com/shows/happy-hour  Hit Listen to see error message.

I have eliminated the HTML5 solution and use only the Flash. This allows any browser to trigger the error.

After dismissing the error Chrome debugger reports a 200 status for the swf so this is not a 404 swf problem.  Anyone have an idea re this error?

After error below is dismissed.

[image: 200 Status]

Chrome error message

[image: chrome error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a jPlayer.ready() function with console output to my initialization. I found it only fired when the player was already visible AND there was no complaint about the Flash solution not being found.

After some more searching based on that result I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339810/jplayer-ready-function-not-triggered-with-flash-solution/25088461):

> "check your styles. if your #jquery_jplayer_1 or its parent has
>   display=none, ready event never fires in such browsers as opera or
>   firefox. i mean flash object can't be hidden."

What was happening was that jPlayer's Flash solution was failing to load because my player had display set to none.

So now I have offscreened player via a negative margin-top and instead of animating height I animate margin-top. It's all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Give the absolute path of your swf folder like `www.mysite.com/js/jQuery.jPlayer.2.4.0`. 
This will help you to test whether the swfPath you gave is wrong or something else.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Tried this just now.  Same sort of error message.  See above for screenshot.

Comment: I have added an update. The SWF is not 404. Sandbox site created to demo issue when only Flash solution is allowed. All browsers see error and after dismissed debugger shows 200 status for swf so error is elsewhere... Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/2.5.0/js/" instead?

Comment: I have added an update.  The SWF is not 404.  Sandbox site created to demo issue when only Flash solution is allowed.  All browsers see error and after dismissed debugger shows 200 status for swf so error is elsewhere... Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If directly going to the path in your browser works and yet it doesnt work inside the script. It could be either:

1. MIME types - check if .swf is being served as `application/x-shockwave-flash`
2. Same origin (cross-domain) policy security, is the .swf file and the executing JS file located in the same domain and being served under the same protocol (HTTP and HTTPS).

If you are willing to post a demo link, we should be able to debug it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Crossdomain.xml has allow-access-from domain="*"   The issue can be observed from http://itsneworleans.com/shows/happy-hour/ in older IE version and I'm told in Safari on Macs.  Windows Safari just uses the HTML 5 player without complaint.  There is a Listen link beside episode description.

Comment: Good news is, I tested it under Mac OS X Mountain Lion and it works! 
[See screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img690/1866/hpde.jpg).

I just tested it under IE7, it does seem like a path problem. Just try to replace `swfPath` with this `http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf`

Comment: I imagine OSX Safari is using HTML5 player which has not had issues.  The swfPath variable has been tried using the jPlayer hosted SWF (error shown above).  Using the value you sent exactly gives error  jPlayer 2.5.0 : id='jquery_jplayer_1' : Error!
jPlayer's Flash fallback is not configured correctly, or a command was issued before the jPlayer Ready event. Details: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'fl_play'
Check your swfPath option and that Jplayer.swf is there.
Context: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf

Comment: I have added an update. The SWF is not 404. Sandbox site created to demo issue when only Flash solution is allowed. All browsers see error and after dismissed debugger shows 200 status for swf so error is elsewhere... Any help appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

just write "../js/jQuery.jPlayer.2.4.0" instead of this it will give you proper solution.
I face same issue in JWPlayer and its worked like this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried this path as well as ./ ../../ and ../.../../  and all of these have same result.  I have added update above with more information: the SWF is not 404.

Comment: To be clear Stack Overflow awarded this bounty due to votes that the answer IN NO WAY EARNED.  It is not an answer to the problem in this post.